# How to create an active-mq ExceptionListener?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, activemq-classic

I have a project coded using Spring-hibernate-activeMq

What I would like to know is if I configured activeMq like I explained below, how should I implement the exception listener class of it? I know you don't understand well now but please give a look to my samples below.

Let me know if I implemented exception listener right or not. If not, please give an example how it must be. Thanks in advance.

**Application context:** (note that I didn't declare any bean for exception listener except the one the property of connectionFactory)

```
<bean id="connectionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory"
      depends-on="broker">
    <constructor-arg ref="amqConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="reconnectOnException" value="true"/>
    <property name="exceptionListener" ref="jmsExceptionListener"/> 
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="100"/>
</bean>
```

**Jms exception listener class:** (Note that I am trying to inject ConnectionFactory, I am not sure whether it is possible or not.. And the last thing, please check the constructor arguments of it, I am also not sure of it..)

```
@Component("jmsExceptionListener")
public class JMSExceptionListener implements ExceptionListener {

private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JMSExceptionListener.class); 

@Autowired
private CachingConnectionFactory connection;

//    private Connection connection = null;

private ExceptionListener exceptionListener = null; 

public JMSExceptionListener() {
}

public JMSExceptionListener(CachingConnectionFactory connection, ExceptionListener exceptionListener) {
    super();
    this.connection = connection;
    this.exceptionListener = exceptionListener; 
}

public void onException(JMSException arg0) {
    logger.error("JMS exception has occured.. ", arg0);

    if(connection != null){
        connection.onException(arg0);
    } 
    if (exceptionListener != null) {
        exceptionListener.onException(arg0);
    } 
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have manipulated exceptionListener class like the following:

```
public class JmsExceptionListener implements ExceptionListener {
private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JmsExceptionListener.class);

@Autowired
private MailService mailService;

private ExceptionListener exceptionListener = null;

private CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory;

public JmsExceptionListener() {
}

public JmsExceptionListener(Connection connection, ExceptionListener exceptionListener) {
    super();
    this.exceptionListener = exceptionListener;
}

public synchronized void onException(JMSException e) {
    logger.error("JMS exception has occurred: ", e);
    sendErrorNotificationMail(e);

    Exception ex = e.getLinkedException();
    if (ex != null) {
        logger.error("JMS Linked exception: ", ex);
    }

    if (exceptionListener != null) {
        exceptionListener.onException(e);
    }
}

public CachingConnectionFactory getCachingConnectionFactory() {
    return cachingConnectionFactory;
}

public void setCachingConnectionFactory(CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory) {
    this.cachingConnectionFactory = cachingConnectionFactory;
}

private void sendErrorNotificationMail(Exception e) {
    try {
        mailService.sendJmsExceptionMail(e, ErrorMessageAccessor.get("core.jms.unexpected"));
    } catch (ElekBusinessException e1) {
        logger.error(ErrorMessageAccessor.get("generic.mailService.exp"), e);
    }
}
```

}